# Problem with 2 decimal places/2 significant figures

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

Lora/GPS Shield + Arduino Uno + PLX-DAQ (latest custom version)

I have a problem on how to generate more than 1/2 decimal output.
Currently, I'm trying to generate GPS Lat and Long(code from TinyGPS++) on PLX-DAQ

[image]

Just like in the image. Latitude generated in 1/2 decimal places.
I'm trying to get more than 2 decimal places.

For example : from 3.2 to 3.123953

Coding link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqjpnsc9pg33f9n/Coding.txt?dl=0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the output from this line?

```
Serial.println( (String) "DATA,DATE,TIME," +flat+ "");
```

drop the use of the String class and make that two separate print statements.  Then you can use the second argument to print to define the precision.

```
Serial.print("DATA,DATE,TIME,");
Serial.println(flat, 6);
```

That gets the same end result output going out the serial line, but lets you specify the precision and avoids the nasty String class.

Comment: Okay, one problem solved. Now how do I get Longitude output same as latitude?

Comment: The same way.  Just print it.  I can't see where in the code you tried to print longitude so I'm not sure what exactly you want to do there.

Comment: This one.

`Serial.print("DATA,DATE,TIME,");
Serial.println(flat, 6); //latitude
Serial.println(flon,6); //longitude`

But the output only latitude. It's like longitude output doesn't work.

Comment: Is it not there at all?  Or is it going to the next line?  Pay attention to when you use print and when you use println.  You should maybe print something in between like a space or a comma or something just to make sure they're separated so you can read them.

Comment: ` float flat, flon;
  Serial.print("DATA,DATE,TIME,");
  Serial.println(flat, 6);
  Serial.print(","); 
  Serial.print(flon, 6);`

this is what i did. Sorry, I'm confuse.

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between print and println?  Would you care to answer the opening question in my last comment?

Comment: Serial.print ("abc");Serial.print("def"); = abcdef
Serial.println("abc"); Serial.println("def"); = abc
def

from what I know.. that's how it prints.

well I did managed to get an output for longitude

btw, thanks for your help.

Comment: Not quite.  println doesn't put a space, it puts a newline after whatever it prints.

Comment: oh, sorry. That not a space. i put "def" in newline. The format for comment here make it just like space.